# why is this code showing NoSuchElementException error? I checked Chrome DOM my XPATH able to find the destinated tag

Tags: python, selenium

why is this code showing NoSuchElementException error? I checked Chrome DOM my XPATH able to find the destinated tag.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    class Firefox():
        def test(self):

            base_url='https://oakliquorcabinet.com/'
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Vicky\Downloads\chromedriver')
            driver.get(base_url)
            search=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="box-footer"]/button[2]')
            search.click()
    ff=Firefox()
    ff.test()
```

Comment: It's a timing issue, add [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: @Guy is correct. It is a timing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium by default waits for the DOM to load and tries to find the element. But, the confirmation pop up becomes visible after some time the main page is loaded.

Use explicit wait to fix this issue.

add these imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

change line in script:

```
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="box-footer"]/button[2]')))
```